# How does the URL match a Controller class in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose I create a Controller named Login, the IDE generates a file like

```
Public Class LoginController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    '
    ' GET: /Login
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function
End Class
```

So when I run my app and enter the following URL

```
http://localhost:49599/Login
```

The controller fires, the view is served, etc.  But wow does the word "Login" get wired to this LoginController class?  What happens if I want to have the option of using a different language and I want to change "Login" to "Logzmein".  I'm suspecting resource files *should* be involved somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the convention-based design of ASP.NET MVC. By default, there are default routes defined that route (or convert) a URL into a controller action method.

By default, routes are defined using the following convention:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

So given a URL like this:

```
User/View/1
```

It break down like this:

`User` (`{controller}`) maps to `UserController` controller class.

`User/View` (`{controller}/{action}`) routes to `UserController.View` action method.

`User/View/1` (`{controller}/{action}/{id}`) routes to `UserController.View` action method, passing in `1` as the `id` parameter.

You can also define custom routes to create your own patterns for routing.

Check out [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) for an overview or routing, because it's too much to cover in a single post.

Comment: So the word "Controller" is always used as part of the class name by convention?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is part of the ASP.NET MVC convention. By naming your classes with `Controller` and in a particular folder (under `Controllers` folder), MVC will locate them based on these default routes.